# executing C from Java strange errors

Tags: java, c, arguments, runtime

I am using Java as a front end for a chess AI i am writing. The Java handles all the graphics, and then executes some C using a few command line arguments. Sometimes the C will never finish, and not get back to the Java. I have found cases in which this happens, and tested them with just the .exe and no java. When i take out the java, these cases work everytime. I am not sure where to go from here. Here is some code that i think is relavant, and the whole project as at https://github.com/AndyGrant/JChess

```
try{
    Process engine = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(buildCommandLineExecuteString(lastMove));
    engine.waitFor();
    int AImoveIndex = engine.exitValue();

    String line;
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(engine.getInputStream()));
    while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) 
        System.out.println(line);
    input.close();

    if (AImoveIndex == -1){
        activeGame = false;
        System.out.println("Fatal Error");
        while (true){

        }
    }

    else{
        JMove AIMove = JChessEngine.getAllValid(types,colors,moved,lastMove,!gameTurn).get(AImoveIndex);
        AIMove.makeMove(types,colors,moved);
        lastMove = AIMove;
        validMoves = JChessEngine.getAllValid(types,colors,moved,lastMove,gameTurn);
    }

    waitingOnComputer = false;
    parent.repaint();
}   

catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Can't tell from what you've posted.  Not willing to read through that project.

Comment: I'm looking for possible errors when executing C programs using RunTime from java.

Comment: If "the C will never finish," can you show that your C code is not stuck in an infinite loop somewhere? If you put a `print` statement right before your `main` function in the C program returns, does it print? Just because you manually gave the C program the correct inputs and it terminated would not necessarily imply the C program should terminate when integrated with the Java program. For example, your Java program could be formatting inputs incorrectly. I wouldn't immediately go to saying that there's some weird error you're making with Runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes, the external process will get stuck on IO, trying to write to the console.  If the console buffer is full, the next printf will block.

How much text is it writing to the console?

Try moving your engine.waitFor() after the part where you read all the input from it.

An alternative would be to have the external process write to a temp file, and then you read the temp file.

Comment: This is the correct answer, sorry for the late response.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe remove

```
while (true){

}
```

If your `AImoveIndex == -1`, your program will enter in a never ending loop.

Comment: I have a print statement before that infinite loop that would indicate a problem.